# Unable to connect to parse in iOS simulator

Tags: parse-platform, ios-simulator, xcode6.3.1

I have used parse.com as my backend for my iOS app and the app is unable to connect to parse when tested on a simulator but it works fine when I test it on my phone. Has anyone ever faced a similar issue it would be great if someone can shed some light on this issue. The error message on the console is

> NSURLConnection/CFURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)
>   2015-05-04 11:50:03.460 AppName[15499:849074] [Error]: The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “api.parse.com” which could put your confidential information at risk. (Code: 100, Version: 1.7.1)

After this it reattempts after few seconds.

Comment: parse.com keeps saying it is resolved and was a temporary bug, but seems there is no solution, https://www.parse.com/questions/the-certificate-for-this-server-is-invalid-apiparsecom and all questions they answer like that.

Comment: I did come across that question once but that seems to be quite sometime back. I'm not sure actually if the problem is on their side or mine. Since its working fine on my device I thought there is something with my simulator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have faced same issue, then i have just checked my device timing. it wasn't appropriate as per GMT. I set it and checked again.then this error disappeared.

Solved the same issue. Check device configuration and time.